# How do I store numbers as varchar in mysql?

Tags: mysql, type-conversion

I have a requirement for storing integer and decimal numbers in my table such as:
`9 , 1, 10.00 , 2 , 100.10`

For this I chose varchar. But the problem is I cannot apply max() function, since it returns `9 instead of 100.10` being datatype varchar. What should I do at this scenario?

Please help!!

 Thanks!!!

Comment: If you are really required to store numbers as strings, you must reply that it isn't possible to do math with strings (but you can offer to sort numbers alphabetically or uppercase them).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one of the [Numeric Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-types.html) available in MySQL. In your case, a [fixed point type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fixed-point-types.html) such as `NUMERIC` or `DECIMAL` or a [floating point type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/floating-point-types.html) such as `FLOAT` would be appropriate.

Comment: Thanks Oswald!! FLOAT serves the purpose. With this, I can store integer & decimal at the same column

Comment: @thabung: Go with `decimal` type. `float` has identified precision based issues.

Answer (score 0):

The variable character data type is useful for storing alpha-numeric characters and not numbers, that is why it reads the first character in your list that is greatest(9). Try using float instead

Answer (score 0):

You can use `convert()` for converting one type to another.[For your Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert)

**Syntax:**

`CONVERT(expr,type)`

Answer (score 0):

Store the values in varchar like you are doing and then cast the values to `Decimal` like

```
SELECT MAX( CAST( mycolumn AS DECIMAL(10,5) )) FROM `mytable`
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your need to store these numbers as a varchar. Do you have any other reason for it? To keep the arithmetic would it not be better to store all numbers as decimal?

DECIMAL(5,2)

Where 5 is the maximum number of digits and 2 being the number of digits after the decimal point, would cover the example numbers in your question. The integer 9 will be stored as 9.00

Comment: Yes, I have other reason. I cannot display as 9.00 to the user and cannot format at my code.